# Apache doesn't recognize mod_auth_openidc commands

Tags: apache, openid, mod-auth-openidc

I'm trying to get the mod_auth_openidc apache module running on an ubuntu server. My problem is, apache doesn't recognize the commands of the module although it is enabled (checked with apachectl -M) and crashes with the following message from systemctl:

```
● apache2.service - LSB: Apache2 web server
   Loaded: loaded (/etc/init.d/apache2; bad; vendor preset: enabled)
  Drop-In: /lib/systemd/system/apache2.service.d
           └─apache2-systemd.conf
   Active: failed (Result: exit-code) since Mo 2016-09-05 15:43:59 CEST; 1min 8s ago
     Docs: man:systemd-sysv-generator(8)
  Process: 4357 ExecStop=/etc/init.d/apache2 stop (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)
  Process: 4383 ExecStart=/etc/init.d/apache2 start (code=exited, status=1/FAILURE)

Sep 05 15:43:59 vbox-ubuntu-shib apache2[4383]:  * The apache2 configtest failed.
Sep 05 15:43:59 vbox-ubuntu-shib apache2[4383]: Output of config test was:
Sep 05 15:43:59 vbox-ubuntu-shib apache2[4383]: AH00526: Syntax error on line 182 of /etc/apache2/apache2.conf:
Sep 05 15:43:59 vbox-ubuntu-shib apache2[4383]: Invalid command 'OIDCProviderMetadataURL', perhaps misspelled or defined by a module not included in the server configuration
Sep 05 15:43:59 vbox-ubuntu-shib apache2[4383]: Action 'configtest' failed.
Sep 05 15:43:59 vbox-ubuntu-shib apache2[4383]: The Apache error log may have more information.
Sep 05 15:43:59 vbox-ubuntu-shib systemd[1]: apache2.service: Control process exited, code=exited status=1
Sep 05 15:43:59 vbox-ubuntu-shib systemd[1]: Failed to start LSB: Apache2 web server.
Sep 05 15:43:59 vbox-ubuntu-shib systemd[1]: apache2.service: Unit entered failed state.
Sep 05 15:43:59 vbox-ubuntu-shib systemd[1]: apache2.service: Failed with result 'exit-code'.
```

Relevant apache2.conf section:

```
OIDCProviderMetadataURL testUrl.com
OIDCClientID testId
OIDCClientSecret testSecret

OIDCRedirectURI http://example.de
OIDCCryptoPassphrase testPassword

Alias "/secure-openid" "/var/www/secure"
<Location /secure-openid>
    AuthType openid-connect
    Require valid-user
</Location>
```

Output of apachectl -M :

```
Loaded Modules:
 core_module (static)
 so_module (static)
 watchdog_module (static)
 http_module (static)
 log_config_module (static)
 logio_module (static)
 version_module (static)
 unixd_module (static)
 access_compat_module (shared)
 alias_module (shared)
 auth_basic_module (shared)
 authopenid_module (shared)
 authn_core_module (shared)
 authn_file_module (shared)
 authz_core_module (shared)
 authz_host_module (shared)
 authz_user_module (shared)
 autoindex_module (shared)
 deflate_module (shared)
 dir_module (shared)
 env_module (shared)
 filter_module (shared)
 mime_module (shared)
 mpm_event_module (shared)
 negotiation_module (shared)
 setenvif_module (shared)
 mod_shib (shared)
 status_module (shared)
```

libapache2-mod-auth-openid version: 0.8-1build1

apache2 version: 2.4.18-2ubuntu3.1

I have absolutely no idea where this problem comes from, thanks in advance for your help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `apachectl -M` output shows the `authopenid_module` module but that is the legacy OpenID 2.0 module from https://github.com/bmuller/mod_auth_openid. You need to make sure that `auth_openidc_module` is loaded instead, which is the OpenID Connect implementation from https://github.com/pingidentity/mod_auth_openidc that you're looking to use.

Comment: I have the same problem, but I am using `auth_openidc_module`. The module seems to be loaded correctly. Could there be other causes for this error?